# How to change the background color behind a TextField helper text in React Material

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield

I have a `TextField` with white background color. But I want the background color of the helper text to be transparent (in this example it will be black) and not white. I can't find a way to set it in `MuiFormHelperText` https://mui.com/material-ui/api/form-helper-text/. It seems that the background colour of the helper text is set by `TextField` in `.MuiTextField-root`. Is it even possible to change the background color of the helper text?

[image: text field helper text]

```
export const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiTextField: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          backgroundColor: '#ffffff' # the background color of the text field,
        },
      },
    },
    // This is not working
    // MuiFormHelperText: {
    //   styleOverrides: {
    //     root: {
    //      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    //     },
    //  },
    // },
  },
});
```

Comment: Are you sure the styles from your theme applied correctly? What happens when you add display: none !important to the text field? Does it hide? Are you sure that the helper text has white bg? In the documentation it is transparent. Are you sure that something else does not override its style?

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that your style is applied, you can use !important flag to give it higher specificity.

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiFormHelperText: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          backgroundColor: 'transparent !important', // Add !important
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

**Another Solution:**

You can try customStyle as well

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  transparentBackground: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
}));


<TextField
  helperText="Your helper text"
  FormHelperTextProps={{
  className: classes.transparentBackground, // Apply the custom class here
  }}
/>
```

Comment: This is not working for me. My helper text still has a white background color.

Comment: You can try custom style. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should isolate the background color change to the text input only. Styling `MuiTextField` changes the whole text field (including the helper text).

```
export const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiInputBase: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          backgroundColor: '#ffffff' # the background color of the text
        }
      }
    }
  },
});
```